# I need to calculate the area of each country

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I am using the naturalearth_lowres pre-set map of geopandas and I need the area in km² of each country for further calculation. I have tried several solutions I found in the internet, but none of them worked for me.

One of he solutions that did not work is [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218450/getting-polygon-areas-using-geopandas). The values I get from this calculation are not fitting the real values at all (compared them with values from wikipedia).

I just need some sort of a formula for the area.

Comment: This is not a Python problem, but really a GIS projection question. Hint: you will have to use an equal-area projection. IMHO you would have better answers on [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I tried to find a solution there, but there were no information valuable for me. The only ones i found were the one i mentioned above and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324921/geopandas-and-qgis-calulating-different-polygon-area-values one. But in both cases I thill get values returned that do not fit the real ones.

Comment: The question you refered used an UTM projection. It is a *conformal* projection not an *equal-area* one, so the surface values are wrong except if the scale is almost constant. It is acceptable for small areas but not for large ones. For large areas you need to use an equal-area projection, and the method in the refered post will work.

Comment: Scrape the values from the wiki page. Or - lower tech - copy them!

Comment: Thank you for you help. I managed to get it running now. I will post an answer for other people having the same problem in the future.

Comment: How accurate do you require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running now:

```
df_copy = df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3035})
df['area'] = df_copy['geometry'].area / 10**6
```

This way I managed to get a satisfactory result, fitting the 'real' values from wikipedia.